# HTML externo em div sem servidor

Tags: javascript, html5, dom

Possuo uma página Index.html é uma série de outras páginas html. Preciso fazer com que o ao clicar em um link o documento específico apareça em uma div. Detalhe, não posso usar o include do PHP pois não posso montar um server por motivos diversos. Não posso usar o load pois ele só funciona no server. Alguém pode me dar uma ideia de como fazer esse milagre? Eu pretendo usar o electron para envelopar tudo, mas pelo teste o load não funcionou no electron tbm. Há alguma maneira do load do jquery funcionar ao executar o HTML no browser ou alguma outra forma de fazer um HTML externo ser escrito direto no dom sem serverside?

Comment: E onde ficam hospedada essa página ?

Comment: No c: de um computador comum. Penso em compartilhar para outros computadores um atalho do Index

Comment: Quando falamos em `jquery` estamos nos referindo a _client-side_ então não entendo porque `load()` do `jquery` não funcionaria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma coisa que acho que pode funcionar.

Estou assumindo que você tem uma div principal com ID "main-content" onde você ira carregar as outras páginas.

```
function load_home() {
   document.querySelector("#main-content").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="PAGINA-HOME.html" ></object>';
}
```

Quando usuario clicar em determinado botão ou link você chama esta função

---

Se você tiver um servidor que rode apenas HTML e precisa de um gerenciamento de rotas, você também pode utilizar angular, assim você terá exatamente o que descreveu.

Uma página principal onde apenas trechos de códigos são alterados.

Veja este exemplo simples do w3c.

https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_routing

Comment: Opa! Excelente. Poxa obrigadao. Vou testar aqui

Comment: Mas saiba que isso não é algo que deva ser feito em uma aplicação que vá para produção. Se for algo apenas para brincar OK, mas um site real nunca faria isso.

Comment: Em um aplicativo local o ideal seria por em um servidor Apache. Correto?

Comment: Sim, você pode instalar o xampp e colocar seu site para rodar nele. Inclusive com o xampp você terá MySql e Php e poderá usar include e fazer do jeito mais correto. Porem o site só sera acessível para pessoas da mesma rede. Você até consegue fazer com que o site se torne visível para todos porem é uma outra história uma configuração dessa, e não recomendaria isso em uma máquina domestica.

Comment: Entendo. É só um quebra galho de testes por enquanto. Muitíssimo obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 1):

Salve um arquivo JS ou inclua no index, com o conteúdo abaixo:

```
function abre(arquivo,alvo){ 
var xmlHttp; try{ xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); }
catch (e){ try { xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); } catch (e){ try { xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }
catch (e){ alert("Seu navegador não suporta AJAX. Atualize-o"); return false; } } }
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function() { if(xmlHttp.readyState == 1) { document.getElementById(alvo).innerHTML = "<img src='images/loading.gif' align='absmiddle'>"; }
if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4) { document.getElementById(alvo).innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText; } }
xmlHttp.open("GET",arquivo,true); xmlHttp.send(null);  };
```

Daí é só colocar no link:

```
<a href="javascript:abre('sobre.html','divEscolhida');">Sobre a Empresa</a>

<div id="divEscolhida"></div>
```

Comment: Repare que tem um: <img src='images/loading.gif' align='absmiddle'> coloque um gif de loading dentro de uma pasta images e pronto.

Answer (score 1):

Nao seria melhor fazer um simples ajax via javascript dando request do aquivo html, e nesta solicitacao vc joga o conteudo dente onde vc vc precisa?

Voce pode tambem criar estes arquivos html somente com o conteudo necessario sem as tags de body e head, somente o que interessa mesmo...

MAS...

Dentro de suas limitacoes diversas, vc pode utilizar angularJS ou algum outro framework javascript para atingir o que necessita de maneira muito mais eficiente do que esta.

Jquery eh legal pra coisa simples em SPA, mas se vc esta fazendo algo mais elaborado, melhor algum framework por tras.

Comment: O problema é a limitação. Não tendo um servidor para hospedar. Os HTML estou colocando só mesmo as tava necessárias, sem HTML,Head e body